# Override settings of jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a plugin  like this :

```
;(function ($,window,undefined){

  ...
  ...default settings area...
  ...content area...
  ...

})(jQuery,window);
```

But this plugin can have many(!) configurations .(files configurations)

So each configuration file can be in a js file . example :

`mySettings.js :`

`var mySetings= {a:1,b:2.....}`

So where is the problem :

- the settings file must be loaded before the plugin. ( so the plugin will be able to read `mySettings`  in the *override settings area*)
- the only way to communicate  `mySettings` with the plugin itself is via the `window` object

Question :

What is the correct way to configure a plugin which can have many(!) settings via js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't have a code example to work with I'll give you some generalized solutions.

1. Collect the settings object(s) in an array and iterate over them within your override settings area.
2. Expose your plugin via window and directly append the settings there.

### [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mVtUd/1/)

**JS**

```
//File 1.js
window.settings = window.settings || []; 
window.settings.push({a:'11'}); 

//File2.js
window.settings = window.settings || []; 
window.settings.push({b:'22', c:'33'}); 

//File3.js
window.settings = window.settings || []; 
window.settings.push({b:'222'}); 

//Main.js File
;(function ($,window,undefined){

    var plugin = function(settings){
        var defConfig = {
            a: '1', 
            b: '2',
            c: '3'
        }; 

        var len = settings.length, i; 

        if(len){
            for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
               defConfig = $.extend(defConfig, settings[i]); 
            }
        }else{
            defConfig = $.extend(defConfig, settings); 
        }

        alert(JSON.stringify(defConfig)); 
    }; 

    var instance = new plugin(window.settings || []); 

})(jQuery,window);
```

### [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mVtUd/2/)

```
//Main.js File
;(function ($,window,undefined){

    var plugin = function(){
        var defConfig = {
            a: '1', 
            b: '2',
            c: '3'
        }; 

        this.overrideSettings = function(settings){
            var len = settings.length, i; 

            if(len){
                for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
                   defConfig = $.extend(defConfig, settings[i]); 
                }
            }else{
                defConfig = $.extend(defConfig, settings); 
            }

            alert(JSON.stringify(defConfig)); 
        }
    }; 

    window.instance = new plugin(); 

})(jQuery,window);


//File 1.js
window.instance.overrideSettings({d:'93'}); 

//File2.js
window.instance.overrideSettings({b:'22222'});
```